# strange thing with connecting to database via asp mvc model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the fallowing exception when i am trying to get models value via generic repository.

```
2014-12-23 14:32:20 ====> System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: Wystąpił błąd podczas wykonywania definicji polecenia. Aby uzyskać szczegółowe informacje, zobacz wyjątek wewnętrzny. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.SurveyUserParameters1'.
   w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   w System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   w System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   w System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   w System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   --- Koniec śladu stosu wyjątków wewnętrznych ---
   w System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   w System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
   w System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   w System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   w System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   w System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
   w System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
   w System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   w System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

I am trying to get by by following lambda expression

`var surveyUserParameters = unitOfWork.SurveyUserParameters.Get()
                                    .Where(x => x.SurveyId == surveyId && x.UserEmail == User.Identity.Name)
                                    .SingleOrDefault();'`

The problem is that exception says that there is invalid object named dbo.SurveyUserParameters1.
My table name is dbo.SurveyUserParameters and there is no way that in applicatino code exist model, variable or something named dbo.SurveyUserParameters1.
I don't know what is going on and I would get some help from You.

Answer (score 1):

Put ctrl+f on your whole solution, and look for `SurveyUserParameters1`. It might be the case of that your model is messed up somehow.

Either try renaming it back to `SurveyUserParameters`, or regenerate the model from database.

Trust me, it's there somewhere :-).

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection string if it has SurveyUserParameters1. Then change it. If not, you might doubled the adding of your db table with your models. Check it as well.